# Set class to checked radio-button in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to generate a bunch of radiobuttons.

```
<div class="radiobutton" ng-repeat="mylabel in field.labels">
    <input
        type="radio" 
        name="{{field['key']}}"
        value="{{mylabel.label}}" 
        id="{{mylabel.name}}"

    >
    <label for="{{field['key']}}">
        {{mylabel.label}}
    </label>
</div>
```

I would like to add a class to the input-element based on if the input-element is checked or not, using angluar. As far as I can understand I should apply a ng-model to the element and then use that to declare a ng-class, but how do I make it so that each input get's it's own model-name?

Comment: is it the same class for all of the radios? something like `.active` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<div class="radiobutton" ng-repeat="mylabel in field.labels">
    <input
        type="radio" 
        name="{{field['key']}}"
        value="{{mylabel.label}}" 
        id="{{mylabel.name}}"
        ng-model='$parent.my_radio_button'
        ng-class='{ class_name: (my_radio_button == mylabel.label) }'
    >
    <label for="{{field['key']}}">
        {{mylabel.label}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Since you use radio buttons, I guess only one can be selected, so you can share the same ng model.

Comment: Hrm I would have thoutght that they needed different models, because when one of the objects were selected all would share the same value, but the == mylabel.label-thing was really smart. This works for making the buttons selected, but not for deselcting them, like ng-click.

Comment: I confirm you only need one ng model for all your radio buttons, actually that's the definition of radio buttons: many options, one possible value

Comment: Yes, it seems as though the model doesn't update when I click the other radio-button. Both become values true... I tried ng_class='my_radio_button' and this confirms my suspicion.

Comment: As loops creates new scopes I had to add $parent. to the model. Now It works.!